# Unable to update edmx diagram

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, edmx

I am unable to update my edmx diagram. The changes are not reflecting.
I tried this method but it doesn't seem to work for me. Any help please?

The method i tried :

```
Go to Model browser. MyStoreProc is the name of the stored procedure (as an example). MyStoreProc will appear in 3 places.

1st place- Under Complex Types-> as MyStoreProc_result
2nd Place- Under Function Imports -> as MyStoreProc
3rd Place - Under Stored Procdures/ Functions -> as MyStoreProc
Delete all three from model. Save the edmx (by clicking in the window then ctrl+S). Then right click and click update the model from database. Then add the updated stored procedure and Save again.
```

Comment: don't think you need to delete it in order to update from DB? Pretty sure you can just double click on the edmx, then in the diagram, right-click and Update Model From Database, and it should just work?

Comment: Its not working actually. So i tried the above method

Comment: not working how? You get an error? There's no reason it shouldn't, unless it's not set up properly somehow. Did you customise the XML of the EDMX or anything?

Comment: like i can't see those two new fields i added in database.. Its not reflecting in complex types.. I didnt try customizing xml

Comment: they are output fields, or input fields? Have you tried deleting and re-creating the EDMX and associated resources (take a backup first, of course!)? Maybe something is just corrupted. Are you definitely connecting to the right instance of the DB? (e.g. maybe you made the change in Dev but DB is pointing to Test)

Comment: I think I am connecting to the right DB. I can check in web.config connection string right?

Comment: From memory I'm pretty sure it double-checks with you when you run the Update Model from Database tool

Comment: @Beginner without readding the edmx, also you can add the newly added columns into the edmx file by using `Add scalar property` via complex types, like wise. And check the appropriate datatype as well. I don't have Edmx file right now in my machine, I am giving a headsup to you. And focus on `Add scalar property`..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided in my question is correct. Due to some issue with multiple database in my system I was unable to update edmx. Thanks for all your help.